# JavaScript: Logic to display unknown number of tiles

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a situation where I get 4, 5 or 6 images/tiles.
Depending on the number of tiles, I need to format the images on the webpage.
Like this http://prntscr.com/9y75dw

If it's five images, I have to format it in such a way that two images in the first row and three images in the second row. Can you help me with the logic?

Comment: How are you getting images ?

Comment: No. I'm a front end dev and I'm asked to write the code for this in JS

Comment: ok. Just provide me your html structure that you want in 3 different case like 4, 5, 6 image

Comment: @vamshikrishna can you include the HTML where you are rendering your images to in your question?

Comment: I don't have the code yet. I was just asked to write logic for this. Let's consider this.

Comment: Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Guys!! help please. Any idea how??

Comment: @vamshikrishna you will need to provide code if you want help, people aren't going to guess at what your page structure is. Once you get code then come back and ask the question

Comment: ``
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
       <div id="tiles"> </div> <!-- display tiles here-->
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I don't see a technique, maybe I am missing to do that more appropriately or in a generic way but since the description in less and number of images given are random, I don't know how this will work.

```
var imageLength = $('img').length;
var newLength = 0, differenceLength=0;

if(imageLength%2==0){
  //incase of even number
  //Do what you like here eg: $('img').css('width', '50%');
}
else{
  // incase of odd number 
  newLength = Math.round(imageLength/2);  //dividing number into two parts.
  differenceLength = imageLength - newLength; //difference to put smaller above and greater below.
  $('parent-div img:nth-child(1)').nextUntil('img:nth-child('+differenceLength+')').wrapAll('<div></div>') //wraps into a container div
}
```

Although this is just one way. You might have already realized a lot of logic by now.

**PS:** *I have randomly written this code so take it as a logic for help. Not sure whether this will work.*